# Get UIImageView rotation value in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rotation, presentation-layer

I'm trying to rewrite an iOS project in Objective-C to Swift in Xcode 6.1 but I can't "translate" this Objective-C line :

```
CGFloat imageRotation = [[self.imageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

How can I get my UIImageView rotation value in Swift?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only slightly more complex in Swift because `valueForKeyPath` returns
an *optional* which has to be unwrapped an then explicitly cast to `NSNumber`.
This can (for example) be done with a combination of optional chaining
and optional cast:

```
let zKeyPath = "layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"
let imageRotation = (self.imageView.valueForKeyPath(zKeyPath) as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0
```

The final "nil-coalescing operator" `??` sets the value to `0.0` if the key path is not
set (or is not an `NSNumber`), this mimics the behaviour of Objective-C where
sending the `floatValue` message to `nil` would also return `0.0`.